# Several combobox categories with several combobox subcategories

Tags: c#, json, uwp, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes with 2 categories and 2 types of subcategories. Combobox categories contain "Usia" and "Serial". Whereas the subcategory combobox retrieves data from the json server. If you select "Usia" in the combobox category, it will display "ratingBox" in the combobox subcategory, and if you select "Serial" in the combobox category, it will display "serialBox" in the combobox subcategory.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="comboBoxStack" Grid.Row="0" Margin="30,15,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox x:Name="kategoriBox" PlaceholderText="Kategori" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="KategoriBox_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBoxItem>Usia</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Serial</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ratingBox" Margin="15,0,0,0" PlaceholderText="Pilih Usia" ItemsSource="{x:Bind RatingList}" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="RatingBox_SelectionChanged"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="serialBox" Margin="15,0,0,0" PlaceholderText="Pilih Serial" ItemsSource="{x:Bind SerialList}" FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="SerialBox_SelectionChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
List<Rating> RatingList = new List<Rating>();
List<Serial> SerialList = new List<Serial>();
string umurID = "";
string serialID = "";

private void KategoriBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBoxItem = kategoriBox.Items[kategoriBox.SelectedIndex] as ComboBoxItem;
            if (comboBoxItem != null)
            {
                string selectedcmb = comboBoxItem.Content.ToString();
                if(selectedcmb == "Usia")
                {
                    ratingBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    serialBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    RatingC();
                    ratingBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
                else if(selectedcmb == "Serial")
                {
                    ratingBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    serialBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    SerialC();
                    serialBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ratingBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                serialBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                RatingC();
            }
        }

        private async void RatingC()
        {
            serialID = "";
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                try
                {
                    string urlPath = "https://..../Fetch/rating";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue.GetObject();
                        string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                        string name = groupObject1["rating"].GetString();

                        Rating rate = new Rating();
                        rate.ID = id;
                        rate.Name = name;

                        RatingList.Add(new Rating()
                        {
                            ID = rate.ID,
                            Name = rate.Name
                        });
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private async void SerialC()
        {
            umurID = "";
            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                try
                {
                    string urlPath = "https://.../Fetch/serial";
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("SCH-API-KEY", "SCH_KEnaBiDeplebt");
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonArray jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue in jsonData)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue.GetObject();
                        string id = groupObject1["id"].GetString();
                        string name = groupObject1["nama"].GetString();
                        string slug = groupObject1["slug"].GetString();

                        Serial seri = new Serial();
                        seri.ID = id;
                        seri.Name = name;
                        seri.Slug = slug;

                        SerialList.Add(new Serial()
                        {
                            ID = seri.ID,
                            Name = seri.Name,
                            Slug = seri.Slug
                        });
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    busyindicator.IsActive = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RatingBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(ratingBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
                Rating value = comboBox.SelectedItem as Rating;
                umurID = value.ID;
            }
        }

        private void SerialBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(serialBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
                Serial value = comboBox.SelectedItem as Serial;
                serialID = value.ID;
            }
        }
```

Rating.cs:

```
class Rating
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }
    }
```

Serial.cs same as Rating.cs

I have a problem, that is if I have chosen "Usia" in the combobox category, then the combobox subcategory for that category can display data on the server smoothly, then I choose "Serial" in the combobox category, eating combobox subcategories for that category can display data on the server with smoothly. Then I again chose "Usia" in the combobox category, so when I click on the subcategory, an error message appears as shown below:
[image: error message]
And here is my PC screen video for my problem:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Auqiv8Ukng7UgP8Fj-LMDa9skV3yfA

In the video when re-selecting "Usia" in the combobox category (at the end of the video), it will display an error message as shown above
How to handle it?

Comment: What's the `Komik()` method? And your 'urlPath' was incomplete. I cannot use it to do more diagnosis. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What's the exception message? In general, if you add some break points to debug your code line by line. You would figure out the issue.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT  no error message, just display the image above

Comment: Your mouse move over the 'e' argument, it should show exception information.